# Two column Page layout with header and footer

Tags: css, layout, graphics, html

I am trying to create two column layout with header and footer so that left bar, header and footer remains fixed and horizontal and vertical scroll should appear on main content on auto what i have achieved so for is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

    .header{width:100%;}
    .left_panel{float:left; width:15%; height:500px; overflow:auto;background-color:#99CCFF;}
    .right_panel{float:left; width:85%; height:500px; overflow:auto;background-color:#FFFFCC;}
    .footer:{width:100%;margin-top:5px;}


</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">

        <h3>HEADER!</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="left_panel">Left Panel</div>
    <div class="right_panel">
            <p class="grey">

        Main content
        </p>


    </div>

    <div style=""></div>

    <div class="footer"><h3 align="center">Footer!</h3></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the footer add in the empty div clear: both in the styling.

Comment: i didn't add clearing div because i am using 100 % width so i think it is not required in above code. In modified version meeting my requirements it may be required :)

Comment: I tryied it and the footer seems ok.

Comment: Scroll does appear if the main context has enought content.

Comment: Add margin-top: 100px to footer. Without clear it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In this case you really won't need the `clear: both` because both the left nav and the main content have the same height, but mind you that the left nav also has `overflow: auto` and it will also show the scroll for that block (if you have a lot of content there).

The main content already has the scrolls, it **depends on the amount of content**.

I made this example http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/pADyc/, reducing the height of the main content so that you can see the effect.

EDIT: Just so you don't be confused, I changed the main content so that it has the original height, and with a lot of content, it obviously shows the vertical scrolls: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/pADyc/1/

And now you may ask about the horizontal scrolls... Well, it will just show them if the content overflows horizontally, which only happens with block elements (div with a wider width, images, text that cannot be wrapped, you get the picture).

Comment: remove clear both from your example and it breaks. Add margin-top: 100px to footer. Without clear it doesn't work

Comment: @George Kastrinis of course it breaks, but with the OP code it doesn't, if both divs have the same height and occuppy the full width, it's impossible to break, check my second jsfiddle and remove the `clear: both` and see for yourself :)

Comment: I need horizontal scroll also in main content can u guide

Comment: @Tassadaque Read my edit, the horizontal scroll will show if the content overflows in the horizontal, in the case of text, normally the browser wraps it to the next line, but try with an image wider than the main content, the scrolls happear.