# Absolute positioned div containing accordion is longer than page. trying to set height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position

I have been working on this for a while and I can't seam to get it right. I have this page:

http://pypestream.hs-sites.com/about

using bootstrap 3 for structuring. The right sidebar is absolute positioned. Unfortunately the pages content isn't tall enough to allow for the height of the sidebar.

I have the content col container mimicking the height of the sidebar which is kind of working (the sidebar is hanging over the footer a bit) but now the issue is that if you open one of the drop downs in the sidebar it doesn't dynamically change the content wrapper to match so the footer doesn't get pushed down. Consequently the sidebar gets cut off.

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Main-Content").css({'height':($(".bios").height()+'px')});
});
```

Comment: _“The right sidebar is absolute positioned”_ – why? Without positioning it absolutely, this should be resolvable without any JS – either using flexbox, or one of the many “faux columns” techniques documented out there, if you need it to work in older browsers, too.

Comment: does you added overflow:hidden to sidebar

Comment: This page is built using the hubspot cos which is based off of bootstrap. I would usually use a custom html module for this but these particular content blocks needs to be editable.

Comment: it is working fine in smaller resolutions. Problebm is only in higher resolutions

Comment: I'm not seeing that, unless you are talking about mobile resolution where I remove positioning... could you give me a size?

Comment: until width is 767px it working fine

Comment: it can be consider as mobile resolution

Comment: Try sticky footer concept Refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837603/yet-another-html-css-layout-challenge-full-height-sidebar-with-sticky-footer